# Is a thread guaranteed to have started when Thread.start() returns?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have tried some sample code along the lines of:

```
Thread thread = new TestThread();
thread.start();
thread.isAlive();
```

It appears to me that the only way for the isAlive() call to return false, is for the thread to have already finished.  Is this true?

The Java 7 JavaDoc for start:

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>   The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.

The Java 7 JavaDoc for isAlive:

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

Neither of these seem very conclusive to me.

Comment: What do you exactly means with "to have started" ?

Comment: In the sample code the thread is likely already died since there is no `Runnable` for for it.

Comment: @draksia How do you know that there is nothing in that TestThread class ?

Comment: @draksia  Agreed, but that was intended as more as psuedo code.  The actual test code I was using involved some sleep timing so that I could make the calls both when I was almost certain the thread would still be alive and vise versa.

Comment: My mistake I thought it was just a `Thread` not an extended version.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The statement `someThread.start()` will cause that thread to go into
  runnable state
- It is not guaranteed that it will start executing its `run` method immediately after `start()` is called.
- Exactly when to execute the thread, is totally dependent on the thread scheduler.
- When `someThread.start()` is called, the thread can move from runnable to runing state and even waiting state.

> Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been started and has not yet died.

This means, the thread is alive when its `start()` is called and its `run()` not completed yet. Completion of `run()` method means thread is dead.

Comment: I'm interpreting this to mean yes, since isAlive() is most likely checking the thread's state and you seem to be indicating that the thread leaves the runnable state synchronously during the call to start.  Correct?

Comment: leaving runnable state is dependent on thread scheduler. `isAlive()` will check the status. A thread can switch between running, runnable and wait state during its `run` method executino

Answer (score 3):

Thread has started doesn't mean it is already executing run method but it's status is Alive.

So after start is returned Thread is alive but not guaranteed to be executing run method it's state can be anything except New after completion of start method. (Runnable, Waiting, Terminated, etc)

```
t.isAlive() returns true if t is not in the NEW or TERMINATED state
```

Also take a look at this great resource on [java threading](http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javathreading/)

Answer (score 2):

A thread `t` is alive as soon as `t.start()` returns and until `t.run()` completes.